# PHP 5.3 - unexpected [

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a `WordPress` site working on a server running `PHP 5.3`. I am not able to update the server so am trying to make things compatible.

I am getting the following error...

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

The line that is causing the error is...

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image($mysection['imageid'], 'medium', "", ["class" => "side_img"] );
```

Any ideas how to modify this code to be compatible?

Comment: in 5.3 arrays need to be declared the old way `array(...)` not `[]`

Comment: Short Array syntax is available since 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 5.3 does not support the "short array syntax" like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. These must be converted to `array(1,2,3,4)`.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 3):

The [short array syntax was first introduced in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). PHP 5.3 does not understand what `["class" => "side_image"]` is, hence the syntax error.

The solution is simple, change:

`["class" => "side_image"]`

into:

`array("class" => "side_image")`